# How to Change .HTMLBody Font Size to 12 pt?

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I am trying to change the font size of certain parts of my email to size 12pt.

11pt and 13pt both work. When trying to set 12pt font it comes out at size 10pt.

Here is a portion of my code:

```vb
.HTMLBody = "Hello All,<br><br>" & _
    "<B><U><font style=""font-size:13pt"">Incidents:</B></U></font><br><br>" & _
    ES11Text & _
    "<B><U>Non Intervention Incidents:</B></U><br><br>" & _
    NonInterventionText & _
    "<B><U>Hand-off:</B></U><br><br>" & _
    "N/A<br><br>" & _
    "<B><U>Escaltions:</B></U><br><br>" & _
    Escalations & _
    "Regards,<br>" & _
    Signature
```

Comment: Have you tried it like this? `<font style=""font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; font-size:12pt"">Incidents:</font>`? or this? `<span style=""font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; font-size:12pt"">Incidents:</span>`

Comment: Just tried that now and it didn't work. Setting it to size 11 or 13 would work in the email, but setting it to 12 will cause it to come out as size 10 in the email.

Comment: You could try using `px` instead of `pt` - you will need to adjust the number accordingly tho.

Comment: You could also try a different `font-family` to see if it behaves the same way.

Comment: I tried that and found that 16 px would be size 12 font but it changes to size 10. It just doesnt make sense

Comment: I figured it out. In my code to generate an email I wanted to include my signature at the bottom so I set a string equal to OutMail.HTMLBody before doing anything else and then concatenate that string to the end of my email which will add my signature. Doing this is what srews it up. If I don't include the signature, Times New Roman 12pt font works... Still doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In my code to generate an email I wanted to include my signature at the bottom so I set a string equal to OutMail.HTMLBody before doing anything else and then concatenate that string to the end of my email which will add my signature. Doing this is what srews it up. If I don't include the signature, Times New Roman 12pt font works... Still doesn't make sense to me.